# Unable to access "use"d class in function

Tags: php, import, namespaces

The bootstrap script contains

```
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\Enum\CannedAcl;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
```

I have a function "aws_s3_put_object" with the code

```
$s3 = Aws::factory('../lib/aws-config.php')->get('s3');
```

but I get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws' not found
```

Why is the class "Aws" not accessible in the function ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: are you including the Aws autoloader or files needed?

Comment: Yes, I am. When I put the the "use" and the "Aws::factory" in the same php script its working.